# Is it possible to create simple REST services with SignalR?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, service, signalr

I recently discovered SignalR, seems that it can fit into high-load projects with hundreds of concurrent connections.

But as far as I can see, it is only supports full communication type of software (real-time).

So here is the question: is it possible to create REST services with SignalR **without client code & persistent connections?**

Basically I just need that **asynchronous high performance** server side part from SignalR & HTTP request handler (if exists).

Regards.

Comment: you want to use SignalR without what SignalR is made for. Seems weird to my eyes.

Comment: If you want simple Rest services have a look at WCF WebMethods or WebAPI

Comment: Well I knew I am in wrong direction. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope that's not SignalR's purpose, use WebApi if you want to make a streaming restful api. Take a look at push content http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/23/using-cookies-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx.