# Integrating AspNet.WebApi with AspNet.SignalR

Tags: asp.net-web-api, real-time, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want to integrate ***Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR version="2.1.2"*** with ***Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi version="5.2.2"*** so that the API can communicate in REAL-TIME. I found one [VERY NICE SAMPLE](https://github.com/bradwilson/WebstackOfLove/) that implements/works exactly the same way I want, but the sample uses jquery.signalR-0.5.0.js. Some of the earlier implementations have changed, and so far here is what I have done in a failed effort to upgrade the solution to use the latest ***signalr, asp.net web api and owin***. 
I left the Hub as it is

```
using SignalR.Hubs;
namespace NdcDemo.Hubs
{
    // This hub has no inbound APIs, since all inbound communication is done
    // via the HTTP API. It's here for clients which want to get continuous
    // notification of changes to the ToDo database.
    [HubName("todo")]
    public class ToDoHub : Hub { }
}
```

I also left the ApiControllerWithHub class as it is

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using SignalR;
using SignalR.Hubs;
namespace NdcDemo.Controllers
{
    public abstract class ApiControllerWithHub<THub> : ApiController
        where THub : IHub
    {
        Lazy<IHubContext> hub = new Lazy<IHubContext>(
            () => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<THub>()
        );
        protected IHubContext Hub
        {
            get { return hub.Value; }
        }
    }
}
```

For the ToDoController, I changed the

```
Hub.Clients.addItem(item), Hub.Clients.updateItem(toUpdate),
 Hub.Clients.deleteItem(id)
```

to

```
Hub.Clients.All.addItem(item), Hub.Clients.All.updateItem(toUpdate),
 Hub.Clients.All.deleteItem(id)
```

and this is now the full ToDoController class

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using NdcDemo.Hubs;
    using NdcDemo.Models;

    namespace NdcDemo.Controllers
    {
        [InvalidModelStateFilter]
        public class ToDoController : ApiControllerWithHub<ToDoHub>
        {
            private static List<ToDoItem> db = new List<ToDoItem>
            {
                new ToDoItem { ID = 0, Title = "Do a silly demo on-stage at NDC" },
                new ToDoItem { ID = 1, Title = "Wash the car" },
                new ToDoItem { ID = 2, Title = "Get a haircut", Finished = true }
            };
            private static int lastId = db.Max(tdi => tdi.ID);
            public IEnumerable<ToDoItem> GetToDoItems()
            {
                lock (db)
                    return db.ToArray();
            }

            public ToDoItem GetToDoItem(int id)
            {
                lock (db)
                {
                    var item = db.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);
                    if (item == null)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(
                            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        );

                    return item;
                }
            }

            public HttpResponseMessage PostNewToDoItem(ToDoItem item)
            {
                lock (db)
                {
                    // Add item to the "database"
                    item.ID = Interlocked.Increment(ref lastId);
                    db.Add(item);

                    // Notify the connected clients
                    Hub.Clients.addItem(item);

                    // Return the new item, inside a 201 response
                    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, item);
                    string link = Url.Link("apiRoute", new { controller = "todo", id = item.ID });
                    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(link);
                    return response;
                }
            }

            public ToDoItem PutUpdatedToDoItem(int id, ToDoItem item)
            {
                lock (db)
                {
                    // Find the existing item
                    var toUpdate = db.SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);
                    if (toUpdate == null)
                        throw new HttpResponseException(
                            Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        );

                    // Update the editable fields and save back to the "database"
                    toUpdate.Title = item.Title;
                    toUpdate.Finished = item.Finished;

                    // Notify the connected clients
                    Hub.Clients.updateItem(toUpdate);

                    // Return the updated item
                    return toUpdate;
                }
            }

            public HttpResponseMessage DeleteToDoItem(int id)
            {
                lock (db)
                {
                    int removeCount = db.RemoveAll(i => i.ID == id);
                    if (removeCount <= 0)
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

                    // Notify the connected clients
                    Hub.Clients.deleteItem(id);

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I put `app.MapSignalR();`
But the demo doesn't work...the API doesn't contact clients...Where am I going wrong?
**I would still appreciate any more simpler recommendations based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368800/can-i-incorporate-both-signalr-and-a-restful-api).**

Comment: If you have found an answer, then take your answer text and post it as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own question and mark it as the answer. It help people who use the site to filter the unanswered from the answered.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

**Answer**:
After a a cup of camomile tea, i found out that the clients had to include the KEYWORD ***CLIENT*** before the dynamic methods in Todo.js... So, here is what that needs to be modified so that the sample works

```
hub.client.addItem = function (item) {
        alert("i just received something...");
        viewModel.add(item.ID, item.Title, item.Finished);
    };
    hub.client.deleteItem = function (id) {
        viewModel.remove(id);
    };
    hub.client.updateItem = function (item) {
        viewModel.update(item.ID, item.Title, item.Finished);
    };
```

And it works!