# Kendo DataSource using Web API and signalR for realtime communication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, signalr

I've built a REST API using web api 2 for handling the CRUD of my grid, this works fine.  I'm trying to now implement SignalR for real time updates (doing something similar as described here [Can I incorporate both SignalR and a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368800/can-i-incorporate-both-signalr-and-a-restful-api)) and it would appear that you MUST use the hubs for all server side operations when using a Kendo DataSource.  I've been searching for some kind of example or documentation that allows for you to possibly use a REST API for CRUD but still allow the client to subscribe to a hub that will push data in real time when something happens with the data.

My question - **Is this possible with the Kendo DataSource and if so how?**

I am following the documentation here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.signalr for configuring SignalR on the client.  Basically though what I would like to do is override the transport.signalr.server configs so that it keep talking to my REST API and just let the client subscribe to the hub so it can receive data in real time.  Kendo's documentation is so sparse I can't tell if this is just not possible or if I'm missing something however.